# Option and Shift keys not working with some combinations, for example (Shift + Option + Command)

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, keyboard

I have a 13' MBP 2012 (non Retina). The problem is that *left* <kbd>Option</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys are not working with some combinations.  For example <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> would not select any text. I can't do a screenshot as well (<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd>/<kbd>4</kbd>).

The problem is with a **left** side only. The right one works great. Also, if I'm using an external keyboard on it left side is working fine.

The keys work fine with a simple combination (<kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>) or <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>something</kbd>. That issue really put me in stuck, because it's so inconstant.

Does anyone face the same issue? As I can remember that behavior appears after I tried to re-assign those keys in Windows Bootcamp (maybe it's just an accident that happened at the same time and it's not actually related). From that time I changed the hard-drive an installed a clean version of latest macOS. The problem still persist.

Any ideas what to do? I don't really want to give it to local services because its price right now is about $400 but they asking $120 for a diagnosis. There are no Apple stores in my or near-by cities.

Comment: Create a new user and try if those shortcuts work there.

Comment: @Joonas did that, unfortunately they did not :(

Comment: The one thing I noticed that is consistent from your question is that `Command` doesn't work.  In the dupe link, I mention that you can use Karabiner elements to remap - for the time being you may want to try that.

Comment: At the very least you can use the EventViewer.app, that comes with Karabiner and see how the keys are registered by it, if at all...

Comment: @Allan  thank you, I installed the app and I can confirm that the issue is a left cmd. I can see that when I hold it (left cmd) the left shift and option key are not registered when I press them. All other keys (1,2,s,da, etc can be registered while I'm holding it) However, even if I hold the left cmd, the right shift and option key is registered! If I hold the right cmd, all works great.

Comment: @Joonas thank you, please take a look at my upper comment!

Comment: I have no idea how to fix this issue. Seems weirds that Shfit and Option would stop working if you hold down Cmd. That would perhaps indicate that the key is not dead and that there is some weird software thing going on. It didn't work properly on a new user account... I wonder if a completely fresh install would solve the issue... or not. I have no idea... I don't know a whole lot about keyboard issues.

Comment: @Joonas thank you, you gave me a great support, hope that issue would never happen to you :)